# MySQL is only updating 1 row when I want it to update more than one, and the WHERE clause allows for both to be updated

Tags: php, mysql

So the purpose of this request is to get friend requests which you have been sent, then set their state in the friend request table to "1", which denotes that the request has been received but not answered yet. Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
$statesent = 0;
$statepending = 1;

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root". "");
mysql_select_db("TagDB");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, username FROM tagusers 
    INNER JOIN friendtable ON tagusers.username = friendtable.userA
    WHERE friendtable.userB = '$username' AND friendtable.state = '$statesent'");

while ($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $output[] = $e;
}

$output = json_encode($output);

print $output;

$requestsgot = mysql_query("UPDATE friendtable SET state = '$statepending' WHERE (userB = '$username' AND state = '$statesent')");
```

This code retrieves the requests just fine, but is only updating a single row of data where userB column value = the username POST, and state = 0. I have more than one which meet both requirements. Any idea why it's only giving me one? I checked for typos and there are none, and besides, I wouldn't be able to get both requests (which I do) if there was a typo present. And what makes this even stranger is that when I move the request from the bottom of the code to the middle, directly after the $query, it will update the opposite row of the one it updates in the position I've posted. It's a strange one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What if my username is `' OR 'a'='a` ?

Comment: I'm assuming for the time being people aren't going to make usernames which break mysql queries

Comment: you should be using prepare and bind (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) as a best practice for mysql statements

Comment: @amccausl You want those around the other way :)

Comment: I'm reading that page, I really don't understand what that does. Can you explain?

Comment: @JMRboosties - You are absolutely positive there are two rows in `friendtable` with the given username and state values and you are positive that absolutely nothing else (e.g. triggers, other processes etc.) is writing to `friendtable` after you execute your Update statement?

Comment: Yes, the code you see there is the php page in its entirety. And doing a SELECT like the answer below suggests returns both fields. Also, when I moved $requestsgot to below $query it updated the opposite row.

Comment: I've been playing with it... now sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, without me altering the code whatsoever. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `UPDATE friendtable SET state = '$statepending' WHERE (userB = '$username' AND state = '$statesent')`

with

`SELECT * from friendtable WHERE (userB = '$username' AND state = '$statesent')`

and see how many records are returned.